# Passing through parameters to stored procedures in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters

I have a stored procedure with the following signature:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`prod`@`%` PROCEDURE `User_Create`(IN login VARCHAR(45), IN pwd VARCHAR(45), IN fname VARCHAR(45), IN lname VARCHAR(45), IN email VARCHAR(45), IN group_name VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `Users` (`login`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `create_time`)
    SELECT login, fname, lname, email, NOW();

    CALL User_UpdatePassword(login, pwd);

    INSERT INTO UserGroupsUsers (`group_id`, `user_id`)
    SELECT ug.id, u.id
    FROM UserGroups ug, Users u
    WHERE ug.`name` = group_name AND u.`login` = login;

END
```

And another one like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`prod`@`%` PROCEDURE `User_UpdatePassword`(IN login VARCHAR(45), IN newpassword VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN

    -- Note that in mysql 5.5.32 SHA2 returns hex so we need to use unhex before calling BASE64_ENCODE
    UPDATE Users u, 
    (
        SELECT CONVERT(BASE64_ENCODE(unhex(SHA2(CONVERT(CONCAT(newpassword, `salt`) USING UTF8), 512))) USING utf8) AS `newpassword`, CONVERT(`salt` using UTF8) AS `newsalt`, length(salt) as saltlength
        FROM (SELECT BASE64_ENCODE(substring(CONCAT(md5(rand()),md5(rand())), 1, 48)) AS `salt`) t1
    ) pwd
    SET u.`password` = pwd.`newpassword`, u.`salt` = pwd.`newsalt`
    WHERE u.`login` = login;
END
```

The issue I seem to be having is that calling:

```
SET @login = 'newlogin' $$
SET @fname = 'Ben' $$
SET @lname = 'Bobbers' $$
SET @email = 'ben@bobbers.com' $$
SET @pwd = 'P@ssword' $$
SET @grpname = 'GrpName' $$

CALL User_Create(@newuser_login, @pwd, @first_name, @last_name, @email, @grpname)
$$
```

Is creating the user and putting it into the group properly, but for some reason User_UpdatePassword does not appear to be passed in the correct parameters. I know the User_UpdatePassword works though because if I then call
Call User_UpdatePassword('newlogin', 'P@ssword') $$

after calling User_Create, it works fine. Somehow it appears that pwd variable is not getting set correctly when User_UpdatePassword is being called from inside another stored procedure. Am I missing somehing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the problem is because you have parameters that are exactly the same name as columns in the tables.  This just invites problems.  Here is the first stored procedure fixed:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`prod`@`%` PROCEDURE `User_Create` (
    IN v_login VARCHAR(45),
    IN v_pwd VARCHAR(45),
    IN v_fname VARCHAR(45),
    IN v_lname VARCHAR(45),
    IN v_email VARCHAR(45),
    IN v_group_name VARCHAR(45)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `Users`(`login`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `create_time`)
        SELECT v_login, v_fname, v_lname, v_email, NOW();

    CALL User_UpdatePassword(v_login, v_pwd);

    INSERT INTO UserGroupsUsers(`group_id`, `user_id`)
        SELECT ug.id, u.id
        FROM UserGroups ug join
             Users u
             on ug.`name` = v_group_name AND u.`login` = v_login;
END;
```

If you fix the other stored procedure, you should solve the problem.

Note that I also fixed the outdated join syntax.